# Como os ORMs, como Active Record, geram código SQL?

Tags: ruby, orm

Gostaria de saber como as ORMs em ruby, transformam uma proc/lambda como esta:

```
{ (id > 1) & (created_at < Time.now) }
```

em algo como `" id > 1 and created_at < '2018-01-25' "`.

Answer (score 3):

## O que é ORM?

De forma simples, um ORM é uma técnica para mapear manipulações de bancos de dados para objetos em linguagens de programação. Uma das funcionalidades de um ORM, como você citou, é converter queries utilizando uma DSL da linguagem utilizada para um dialeto SQL.

## O Active Record

É por isso que no Active Record (o ORM padrão do Rails) isso:

```
Car.find_by(name: 'Opala')
```

se traduz para

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE name = 'Opala' LIMIT 1
```

## Por baixo dos panos...

E como isso funciona? Bem, vamos ao [código do #find_by](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/94b5cd3a20edadd6f6b8cf0bdf1a4d4919df86cb/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L80):

```
def find_by(arg, *args)
  where(arg, *args).take
rescue ::RangeError
  nil
end
```

Parece que ele chama um método chamado `#where`. Isso é interessante, pois parece que várias palavras do SQL foram escritas em suas versões Ruby. Vamos mais a fundo, ao [código do #where](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/94b5cd3a20edadd6f6b8cf0bdf1a4d4919df86cb/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L578).

```
def where(opts = :chain, *rest)
  if :chain == opts
    WhereChain.new(spawn)
  elsif opts.blank?
    self
  else
    spawn.where!(opts, *rest)
  end
end
```

Não se assuste com esses `if`s. Isso se dá pois o `#where` pode ser utilizado de diversas formas, como por exemplo:

```
User.where.not(name: "Jon")
```

Porém, o tipo de `#where` que estamos utilizando aqui é o Hash, com o argumento `{ name: 'Opala' }`. Sendo assim, ele cai no `else`, para o método `#where!`. [Vamos ao código!](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/94b5cd3a20edadd6f6b8cf0bdf1a4d4919df86cb/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L588)

```
def where!(opts, *rest) # :nodoc:
  opts = sanitize_forbidden_attributes(opts)
  references!(PredicateBuilder.references(opts)) if Hash === opts
  self.where_clause += where_clause_factory.build(opts, rest)
  self
end
```

Agora parece que estamos no caminho que chegar em algo um pouco mais "baixo nível", onde ele realmente monta uma string com código SQL, que afinal, é o produto final de um ORM. Veja o que esse método `where!` faz:

- Sanitiza os dados para evitar erros de sintaxe e ataques como injeção de SQL
- Adiciona uma cláusula a query, que é salva em memória por uma variável de instância, chamada `where_clause`

O interessante desse método é o trecho `where_clause_factory.build(opts, rest)`. Veja [o código](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/94b5cd3a20edadd6f6b8cf0bdf1a4d4919df86cb/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L1192):

```
def where_clause_factory
  @where_clause_factory ||= Relation::WhereClauseFactory.new(klass, predicate_builder)
end
```

(se você não conhece o "pipe pipe equals / or equals) do Ruby, `||=`, dá [uma olhada aqui](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html))

O `#where!` chama o `Relation::WhereClauseFactory#build`. Essa fábrica de clausulas `WHERE` vai analisar o input, que no nosso caso é `{ name: 'Opala' }`, para montar a query.

No Active Record, esse input pode vir de várias maneiras, como:

- Filtros de campos da tabela. Por exemplo: `{ name: 'Opala' }`
- Filtros de range. Por exemplo: `{ year: 1999...2000 }`
- Filtros de relacionamento da tabela. Por exemplo: `{ pilot: { id: 1 } }`
- E outros...

Essa fábrica gera uma só instância de [`WhereClause`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b5302d5a820b078b6488104dd695a679e5a49623/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/where_clause.rb#L5), adicionando ou removendo as condições do `WHERE`.

## O bilíngue: montando a query

Até agora, só falamos Ruby e Active Record.

Depois de montada toda a [árvore da query](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/94b5cd3a20edadd6f6b8cf0bdf1a4d4919df86cb/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L926), armazenada em memória em classes como `WhereClause`, o Active Record chama um "montador de queries SQL", chamado [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel).

O papel do Arel é falar Ruby e SQL ao mesmo tempo, conseguindo ler o código Ruby e traduzir para SQL (por definição, o Arel é um SQL Abstract Syntax Tree).

[image]

O conceito de AST é utilizado por compiladores e outras linguagens de programação como uma representação abstrata do código, ou qualquer outra estrutura sintática, como o bom e velho Português.

Um exemplo matemático ([fonte](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/254075/285228)):

```
5 * 3 + (4 + 2 % 2 * 8)

     +
    / \
   /   \
  *     +
 / \   / \
5   3 4   *
         / \
        %   8
       / \
      2   2
```

E um exemplo do JavaScript:

[image]

Veja um exemplo do Arel montando queries:

```
users = Arel::Table.new(:users, ActiveRecord::Base)

select_manager = users.project(Arel.star).where(users[:id].eq(23).or(users[:id].eq(42)))
select_manager = users.project(Arel.star).where(users[:id].eq_any([23, 42]))
select_manager.to_sql
# => SELECT * FROM "users"  WHERE ("users"."id" = 23 OR "users"."id" = 42)
```

O Active Record converte as classes próprias (`WhereChain`, `WhereClause`, `GroupClause`) e as converte em chamadas do Arel, "cuspindo" queries complexas montadas com DSLs simples, fáceis e Rails-like.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade a minha duvida era outra, não estava em duvida de como a querie é criada. a minha duvida basicamente era essa:

Como é transformada uma expressão como essa: `{ (id > 1) & (created_at < Time.now) }`
que é basicamente uma lambda sem parâmetros, numa string: `id = 1 and created_at < data_atual`

sabendo-se que `id` e `created_at` são definidos somente dentro desse bloco.

Resposta

No caso é usado o método `instance_exec` com uma `class` e os métodos não definidos, são criados dinamicamente, assim como seus comparadores, fazendo com que retornem uma string.

lembrando que o `instance_exec` captura uma lambda e usa os somente os métodos definido na `class` ou seja, se você colocar um `print` dentro desse bloco, haverá um erro porque a função não foi definida.

Basicamente o que posso concluir disso tudo é que, no caso da `ORM Sequel` fizeram isso só pra dizer que conhecem bem a linguagem, pois dificultaram o um processo simples que é escrever uma string.